# iterators for std::accumulate

Tags: c++, c++11

The error seems to be with `std:: accumulate()` or the iterators, or am I accessing an invalid pointer?

```cpp
int m = 0;
std::vector<int> v{4,-3,0,-5};
for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
{
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator j = v.begin(); j != v.end(); j++)
    {
        m = max( m,  std::accumulate(i, j, 0)  );
    }
}
```

I've tried the above code, but the program stops unexpectedly.

Comment: As an aside, the code can (and should) trivially be changed from O(n³) to O(n²). With O(n) space (overwrite `v` or extra), even O(n) is possible.

Comment: @JeJo I rolled back your edit because it altered the semantics of the OP's original code that was being asked about. Cleaning up someone's formatting is OK, but don't alter the logic of someone's code to make it work differently, especially in a question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thought, neglecting(OP) `main()` is something what obvious, and will not alter anything special for what he asked. Sorry if my edit was misleading. Thanks for the revert.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `j` can be less than `i`. This version works

```
int m = 0;
std::vector<int> v{4,-3,0,-5};
for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i!=v.end(); i++)
{
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator j = i; j!=v.end(); j++)
    //                             ^^^^^^
    {
        m = max( m,  std::accumulate(i, j, 0)  );
    }
}
```